# How to route a specific users IP from WAN to a specific host IP on a subnet OPT1 (pfsense)

Tags: c#, networking, lua, network-programming

Hello I host a game server, Players and Devs use the same launcher/client that has hard coded ports (5555) that cannot be changed. (No Configuration Files)
How would I route Devs to the Development Server [OPT1] 172.1.1.4:5555 and Players to the Production Server [LAN] 10.1.1.49:5555?

[My Network] https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpDdY.jpg

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Network Engineering.SE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @madreflection Thank you very much for the advice,  I have done so.